error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining when repo syncing
I am facing this error when i try to repo sync
Previous Command:
mkdir cm
cd cm
repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b cm-12.1
repo sync -c -j8

While repo syncing:
remote: Enumerating objects: 76190, done.        
Receiving objects:   0% (1/76190)
Receiving objects:   0% (173/76190), 28.00 KiB | 29.00 KiB/s
...
Receiving objects:  61% (46952/76190), 11.64 MiB | 108.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects:  61% (46952/76190), 11.71 MiB | 100.00 KiB/s
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Fetching:  5% (32/540) 5:00 | 8 jobs | 4:59 LineageOS/android_development @ de..

It retries and making the same output until it just skips it and the repo sync still runs. Any solution to this problem? Or i am doing something wrong?
I have tried:

Increaseing buffer size
Turning off the compression
using HTTP/1.1

git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1


Editing the ~/.gitconfig file and adding

[core] 
packedGitLimit = 512m 
packedGitWindowSize = 512m 
[pack] 
deltaCacheSize = 2047m 
packSizeLimit = 2047m 
windowMemory = 2047m

NOTE:
When using HTTP/2. I get a error
Receiving objects:  46% (3280/7004), 12.81 MiB | 148.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects:  46% (3282/7004), 13.04 MiB | 188.00 KiB/s
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

I am on ubuntu server (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS)
Git version 2.25.1
